# Hide certain elements inside listview onclick

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview that is shown in the image linked below. What I wanted is that after clicking on the "Accept Order" button, the button would be hidden and another togglebutton that is originally hidden will become visible. This behaviour will only affect the clicked row and will not affect the other rows inside the listview (The other rows will still show accept order button).How do I set the onclicklistener for the button?

[image: Listview in question]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1-** First you need a List of **Custom Objects** for each row.
Each Object should have a boolean value which controls the state of Buttons of each different row.

Example:

```
public class Order {
    private String title;
    private boolean isAccepted;

    public Price(String title, boolean isAccepted) {
        this.title = title;
        this.isAccepted = isAccepted;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public boolean isAccepted() {
        return isAccepted;
    }

    public void setIsAccepted(boolean isAccepted) {
        this.isAccepted = isAccepted;
    }
}
```

**2-** Create an ArrayList of Order class(or whatever you have) and set your data. Your logic can be like "if isAccepted == **true**, then **hide** Show Order Button" Set your data by using this logic.

**3-** Set an adapter to list your Items in a listView. In your adapter, set onclicklistener to your buttons and when you clicked a button, set your boolean value on the correct position of the list. Then Notify/Update your adapter.

If you have any further questions, check [this simple example](http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.com.tr/2010/03/clicking-buttons-in-listview-row.html).

Comment: v.getParent() and getChildAt(int index) as used inside your linked example is what I needed ! thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the ListView you have to set an adapter, which provides

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

There you set the `onClickListener` for the button and the visibility for the corresponding togglebutton.

The particular view is referenced by

```
convertView.searchViewById(int)
```

For an ListView example, please take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)